# Frame fillRect setColor not working

Tags: java

I can open up the java app, but I'm not seeing any color or the 4 rectangles I created, I don't see any errors, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I've tried looking into why it isn't creating them, but I can't see why it isn't. Shouldn't the fillRect be created or am I missing something here?

simon.java

```
public class Simon implements ActionListener
{

public static Simon simon;

public Renderer renderer;

public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

public Simon()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simon");
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

    renderer = new Renderer();

    frame.setSize(WIDTH + 15, HEIGHT + 38);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(renderer);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    timer.start();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    simon = new Simon();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

    renderer.repaint();

}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) 
{

    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH + 15, HEIGHT + 35);

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(WIDTH / 2, 0, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);

    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);




}

}
```

Renderer.java

```
package Simon;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Renderer extends JPanel
{
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(Simon.simon !=null)
    {   
        Simon.simon.paint((Graphics2D) g);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I copied your code exactly as written and ran it.  Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Hmmm I thought they may be the case, I'm running it on a Mac and it isn't showing. I'm guessing you ran that on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I did run it on Windows (7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not extendable.

Here's a Simon Says GUI I put together.  It displays the first 10 computer sequences, one at a time.

[image: Simon Says]

First, I create the GUI.  I draw the circle segments on an extended JPanel.  I create and keep the information about the game in a game model.  By separating the model from the view and the controller, I can focus on one part of the game at a time.

And here's the code.  I put all of the classes together to make it easier to paste the code.  You should separate the classes into their own files.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimonShape implements Runnable {

    private GameModel gameModel;

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimonShape());
    }

    public SimonShape() {
        this.gameModel = new GameModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Simon Says");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        GameRunnable runnable = new GameRunnable(drawingPanel, gameModel);
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 70146219705119575L;

        private List<ArcModel> segments;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.segments = new ArrayList<ArcModel>();

            int margin = 50;
            int diameter = 300;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(margin, margin, diameter, diameter);

            segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.GREEN, r, 180, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
            segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.BLUE, r, 270, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
            segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.RED, r, 360, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
            segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.YELLOW, r, 90, 90, Arc2D.PIE));

            int width = diameter + margin + margin;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width));
        }

        public void brighterArcModelColor(int index) {
            segments.get(index).brighterColor();
            repaint();
        }

        public void darkerArcModelColor(int index) {
            segments.get(index).darkerColor();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            for (ArcModel arcModel : segments) {
                g2d.setPaint(arcModel.getColor());
                Rectangle r = arcModel.getRectangle();
                g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r
                        .getHeight(), arcModel.getStartingAngle(), arcModel
                        .getExtent(), arcModel.getClosureType()));
            }
        }

    }

    public class ArcModel {

        private final int closureType;

        private final double startingAngle;
        private final double extent;

        private Color color;
        private final Color originalColor;

        private final Rectangle rectangle;

        public ArcModel(Color color, Rectangle rectangle, double startingAngle,
                double extent, int closureType) {
            this.color = color;
            this.originalColor = color;
            this.rectangle = rectangle;
            this.startingAngle = startingAngle;
            this.extent = extent;
            this.closureType = closureType;
        }

        public int getClosureType() {
            return closureType;
        }

        public double getStartingAngle() {
            return startingAngle;
        }

        public double getExtent() {
            return extent;
        }

        public Rectangle getRectangle() {
            return rectangle;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void brighterColor() {
            this.color = Color.WHITE;
        }

        public void darkerColor() {
            this.color = originalColor;
        }

    }

    public class GameModel {

        private List<Integer> computerSequence;
        private List<Integer> playerSequence;

        private Random random;

        public GameModel() {
            this.computerSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            this.playerSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        public void addToComputerSequence() {
            computerSequence.add(Integer.valueOf(random.nextInt(4)));
        }

        public void clearComputerSequence() {
            computerSequence.clear();
        }

        public List<Integer> getComputerSequence() {
            return computerSequence;
        }

        public void clearPlayerSequence() {
            playerSequence.clear();
        }

        public void addToPlayerSequence(int number) {
            playerSequence.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
        }

        public boolean doSequencesMatch() {
            if (computerSequence.size() == playerSequence.size()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < computerSequence.size(); i++) {
                    int computer = computerSequence.get(i);
                    int player = playerSequence.get(i);
                    if (computer != player) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }

    public class GameRunnable implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean running;

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        private GameModel gameModel;

        public GameRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel, GameModel gameModel) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
            this.gameModel = gameModel;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            running = true;
            while (running && gameModel.getComputerSequence().size() < 10) {
                generateComputerSequence();
                sleep(1800L);
            }
        }

        private void generateComputerSequence() {

            gameModel.addToComputerSequence();
            for (Integer index : gameModel.getComputerSequence()) {
                drawingPanel.brighterArcModelColor(index);
                sleep(1000L);
                drawingPanel.darkerArcModelColor(index);
                sleep(200L);
            }

        }

        private void sleep(long duration) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is amazing first of all. It looks fantastic, and I was able to separate it all into classes. In the example that I have I was able to work with someone to get it to work on the windows machine I have, but I do know that I need it to work on a mac as well. Thing is, yours is automatically playing itself? Is there anything that can happen here to help with having it playable? What needs to happen? Thanks.

Comment: @koawinter: You'll have to add an input method for the player.  My suggestion would be mouse clicks.  You'll have to modify the GameRunnable class to allow for the player input, and check to see that the player sequence matches the computer sequence.

Comment: Awesome, one last question. How would you add a reset button that keeps tabs of all the games you've played and at the end of each game posts the score of that round and the high score of all the games played? Would I create a separate class for the score?

Comment: @koawinter: The reset button action listener has to reset the game model.  Yes, I'd create another class to keep the high scores, mainly because you'll have to write the high scores to a file and read the high scores from a file.  Check out my [Minesweeper Applet](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=300) article to see how I created and maintained a high score display.

Comment: I've updated the link to my [Minesweeper game](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/minesweeper).  I converted the applet to a Swing GUI.